# AWS DUPLICATE_CLIENT_ID

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-greengrass

I have a Jetson, set up as core device. It has greengrass installed on it (inc. deployments, components etc)
I want to set up an AWS SSH tunnel, installed and configured the aws-iot-device-client, but it gets disconnected. In the AWS console at MQTT Test I get the error message DUPLICATE_CLIENT_ID.
Any thoughts or ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AWS IoT Greengrass V2, you can deploy the AWS-provided [Secure Tunneling component](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/secure-tunneling-component.html) to install and configure the AWS IoT Device Client for you, so you can create SSH tunnels. This component uses the Greengrass nucleus' MQTT connections, so it avoids the duplicate ID error.

Comment: Thanks, I have also found that component in the mean time :)